# Are finite sets of points in projective space non-singular.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let's say we have a projective algebraic set $X = \{p_1,...,p_n\}$ that's just a finite set of points. Is X non-singular? My understanding is that a variety/algebraic set is non-singular if the tangent space at each point has the same dimension as the variety/algebraic set itself, but I don't know what the tangent space of a single point would be.

Comment: 1. Your title and body questions do not match. 2. You are missing your definitions - this is extra unfortunate because the question in the body boils down to "can I apply this definition," which again, is missing! 3. Can you be more specific about why you think there may be issues with applying your definition of smoothness in the setting you're asking about? Please improve your post with an [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your base field $k$ is characteristic $0$ or algebraically closed, $X$ is always non-singular, and the morphism $X\rightarrow spec(k)$ is smooth(and etale) in these cases.

If you are in the setting of classical algebraic geometry, when $k$ is algebraically closed, the dimension of X is $0$, and the tangent space at each point is again $0$, so it is indeed non-singular.

But in modern setting, when $k$ is an arbitrary field, the answer to your question depends on whether the residue field at each $p_i$ is separable over $k$ or not. As a scheme, X is just the spectrum of a product of finite extension of your base field(assuming each $p_i$ is a closed point, but this is necessary for X to be a closed subset of $P^n$), i.e. $X= spec(\prod k_i)$, where each $k_i$ is a finite extension of $k$, your base field. When all these extensions are separable, the morphism $X\rightarrow spec(k)$ is smooth(actually, etale), and $X$ is a non-singular variety(if you call it a variety). The separable condition is always satisfied when $k$ is char $0$ or algebraically closed, but not always so in char $p$. Just like @KReiser mentioned, the case $F_p(t)/F_p(t^p)$ may happen, when you let your base field $k=F_p(t)$, and let $p$ to be the point in $P^1=Proj(k[x,y])$ corresponds to the polynomial $x^p=ty^p$.

Generally, the tangent space of a variety at a point is defined to be the dual of the stalk of the sheaf of relative differentials, i.e. $T_xX=\Omega_{X/k,x}^*$  . And smoothness is defined to be flat + relative differential locally free of the same relative dimension. When K/k separable, it is known that $Ω_{K/k}=0$.

In any case, $X$ is always a regular scheme.

Answer (score 1):

It is non-singular.

The dimension of X is $0$, and the tangent space at each point is again $0$.

Or more directly, as a scheme, X is just the spectrum of a product of finite extension of your base field(assuming each $p_i$ is a closed point, but this is necessary for X to be a closed subset of $P^n$), i.e. $X= spec(\prod k_i)$, where each $k_i$ is a finite extension of $k$, your base field. Which is smooth(actually, etale) over $spec(k)$, and non-singular particularly. It is also a regular scheme.

Comment: Assuming that $p_i$ are different.

Comment: Your "or more directly" paragraph is not completely correct and not obviously applicable. A finite extension need not be smooth: consider $\Bbb F_2(t^2)\subset \Bbb F_2(t)$. The whole discussion of schemes might be a bit much for someone who's posting history indicates no engagement with the concept.

Comment: @KReiser You are right ! My bad !! The finite extension is etale iff it is a separable extension. When $k$ is characteristic $0$, or when $k$ is algebraically closed, this is always right(so in these cases, X is indeed, a non-singular variety; or smooth, or etale over $k$), but in characteristic $p$, the case you mentioned may indeed happen in $P^n$ ! So the answer is that it depends on whether the residue field is separable over $k$ or not. I think in the original question, the setting is probably over an algebraically closed field so it need not to be too complicated.

Comment: By the way, just to mention, the tangent space of a variety at a point is defined to be the dual of the stalk of the sheaf of relative differentials, i.e. $T_xX = \Omega_{X/k,x}^*$. And smoothness is defined to be flat + relative differential locally free. When $K/k$ separable, it is known that $\Omega_{K/k}=0$.